# How do I get sscanf to run in unix with a structure?

Tags: c, unix, scanf, structure

I'm trying to do as the comments state, however my sscanf statement is not working.  Am I supposed to initialize the variables for dob prior to using sscanf?  My program keeps giving me warnings that they aren't initialized but after running it skips over my sscanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define a structure called  dob  that contains an array for month,
//    an integer for day, and an integer for year

typedef struct{
  char month[3];
  int day;
  int year;
}dob;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   // declare a variable  bday  whose type is the structure  dob
   dob bday;

   // show  sscanf() statements to get the values entered at the
   // command line into the variable  bday if user enters the following:
   // Jan 31 1967 = input   
   // ./a.out Jan 31 1967

   sscanf("%s %i %i", bday.month, bday.day, bday.year);


   // finish the printf statement below
   printf("Your birthday is: %s %d, %d\n",  bday.month, bday.day, bday.year);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Don't use `month[3]`.  Use at least `month[4]`, and pair it with `%3s` in your `sscanf` statement.

Comment: You have missed out the `&` before some of the arguments in `sscanf("%s %i %i", bday.month, bday.day, bday.year);`, which should be `scanf("%s %i %i", bday.month, &bday.day, &bday.year);` – don't ignore warnings, deal with them.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure month can hold 3 chars plus a null terminator: `char month[4];`

Initialize dob, and a buffer for input:

```
  char inbuf[80] = {0};
  dob bday = {0};
```

Don't forget to let the user input some data:

```
  fgets(inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), stdin);
```

Call sscanf correctly, with an input string to scan before the format string (Note, limiting the string scan to 3 chars to be memory safe), then the addresses of the members you want to modify:

```
  sscanf(inbuf, "%3s %i %i", bday.month, &bday.day, &bday.year);
```

Comment: Also -- check the return value of sscanf to see how many items were scanned successfully.  In this case, if it is less than 3, there was a problem with the input, and `bday.year` (at least) will still be uninitialized.